# Without using any additional libraries, how would someone approach the challenge of reading the metadata of .pdf files in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, metadata

I know this is not an easy question and I do not expect an easy answer. I want to learn more about this, and the only way to do it is the hard way.

What first steps should I take?

Comment: Step 1: Write a PostScript parser.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you develop the answer a little bit more?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/PostScript-Language-Tutorial-Cookbook-Systems/dp/0201101793/

Comment: I will take this into consideration.

Comment: I don't think that reading about postscript will help in this case. PostScript and PDF are very different, and the metadata part in particular is completely unrelated.

Comment: Sort of depends where you're starting from. Can you read a standard? Have you ever worked with binary file formats before? Have you ever used Python before? In common with other ISO publications, the PDF standard is astonishingly expensive, but you can download older versions (and notes on Adobe's extensions) from the Adobe website.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I know to do all those things. They are fairly easy to do. I've also taken into consideration reading Adobe's reference for PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get 'CreationDate', 'Author' and this kind of entries you can try this quick and dirty solution.
Normally this information in a pdf should look like this:

```
obj
<<
/Author(NameOfAuthor)
/CreationDate(D:20040910110429)
/Producer(AcrobatPdfWriter)
>>
endobj
```

Not sure if applies for all pdf formats but I got some decent data that you can 'clean-up' after. Only works if the entries are on separate lines.

```
metadata_fields = ['Creator', 'CreationDate', 'Producer', 'ModDate']
with open('path_to_your_file.pdf') as my_pdf:
  meta_values = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in my_pdf.readlines() 
             for item in metadata_fields if item in line]
  print meta_values
```

Output:

```
['<</Producer(AFPL Ghostscript 8.11)', '/CreationDate(D:20040910110429)',
 '/ModDate(D:20040910110429)', '/Creator(PDFCreator Version 0.8.0)']
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks for making the effort of writing it.

Comment: I just realized it only works if the entries are on separate lines which is not the case most of the time...